# Object Chasing Another Object

Tags: python, animation, objects

I have two objects, ***Object A*** and ***Object B***. ***Object B*** can be constantly moving whatever I set its position to be, or it's movement. It could also not be moving at all. I want to be able to make it so that ***Object A*** chases ***Object B*** (by moving towards it every frame) at a constant speed where if ***Object B*** changes position, ***Object A***'s direction of movement changes as well. I am using normal Blender Render, so can someone suggest me an easy way to do this, even if it involves Python coding. It's basically making an object face another and translating on its own local forward.

Want I **don't want** is the two objects two have their vertex positions linked to each other so if I drag one in the editor, the other one will move as well (aka parenting). **I do not want that**.

This means that if ***Object A***'s speed is set to ***0***, then changing ***Object B***'s position won't affect ***Object A***'s position.

Again I want that so as I play the animation frame by frame, the first object is moving towards the second object at a constant speed and the second object itself can move somewhere else which will change the heading of the first object in order to still be following the second object.

Comment: Have you tried setting your objects to follow a curve as opposed to parenting A to B?

Comment: I did think about that but it means I have to figure overly complicated math equations and it gets even hard when object b moves conplicatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I put together to answer this q about a month ago, noticed it active and dug it up.

Before running script set up a scene with a sphere named "Sphere" and a cone named "Cone", give the cone a track to constraint to make it face the sphere.  The Cone is given a speed custom property.  Animate the sphere and the cone will track it.  This is done with frame change handlers.

NB: Need to fix for when the speed is zero, the track to constraint has no effect, (simple driver) `1 if speed > 0.0 else 0` and what to do when the objects collide.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

obA = scene.objects.get("Cone")
obA["speed"] = 0.01

obB = scene.objects.get("Sphere")
preloc = obB.matrix_world.to_translation()

def getloc(scene):
    global preloc
    preloc = obB.matrix_world.to_translation()

def setloc(scene):
    global preloc

    # set location for frame 1
    if scene.frame_current == 1:
        obA.location = (10, 10, 10)

    loc = obB.matrix_world.to_translation()
    v = loc - preloc
    if v.length > 0.000001: # it has moved
        print(scene.frame_current, v)

    # move object A towards B
    dv = loc - obA.location

    speed = obA["speed"]
    print(dv.length)
    if speed > 0.000001 and dv.length > 0.000001:
        obA.location += speed * dv.normalized()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()  
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(getloc)
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(setloc)
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I want. I will check it out when I get home.

Comment: I'm still not home yet...